# How to Write a Value Into a Chosen Row and Column in SQLite using Python

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite

So I'm trying to work with an SQLite database at the moment and was hoping to get some input on the best way of writing a value to a particular row and column (so cell) of a database. I know how to write to the database row by row, so basically appending a row to the end of the database each time, but instead I would like to write the data into the database non sequentially.

I have put together an arbitrary example below to illustrate what I'm trying to do by using apples. In this case I create two tables in a database. The first table will be my ID table and is called *apples*. This will contain a primary key and two columns for the apple name and the farm it is grown in. The second table *keyFeatures* will contain the primary key again which refers back to the ID of the apple in the apple table, but also a column for the taste, texture and the colour.

In the example below I have only the taste, texture and colour of the apple Pink Lady from farm 3. I now want to write that information into row 3 of the table *keyFeature* in the relevant columns before any of the other rows are populated. For the life of me I can't work out how to do this. I assume I need to position the cursor to the correct row, but from the documentation I am not clear on how to achieve this. I'm sure that this is a trivial problem and if anyone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!

```
import sqlite3

dbName = 'test.db'

################# Create the Database File ###################

# Connecting to the database file
conn = sqlite3.connect(dbName)
c = conn.cursor()

#Create the identification table with names and origin
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE apples(appleID INT PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, 
farmGrown TEXT)''')

#Create the table with key data
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE keyFeature(appleID INT PRIMARY KEY, taste INT, 
texture INT, Colour TEXT)''')

#Populate apples table and id in keyFeature table
AppleName = ['Granny Smith', 'Golden Delicious', 'Pink Lady', 'Russet']
appleFarmGrown = ['Farm 1', 'Farm 2', 'Farm 3', 'Farm 4']
id = []

for i in range(len(AppleName)):
    id.append(i+1)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO apples(appleID, Name, farmGrown)
                    VALUES(?,?,?)''', (id[i], AppleName[i], appleFarmGrown[i]))

    c.execute('''INSERT INTO keyFeature(appleID)
                    VALUES(?)''', (id[i],))


#Current Apple to populate row in keyFeature
appleCurrent = (('Pink Lady','Farm 3')) 

tasteCurrent = 4
textureCurrent = 5
colourCurrent = 'red'

#Find ID and write into the database

c.execute("SELECT appleID FROM apples")
appleIDDB = c.fetchall()

c.execute("SELECT name FROM apples")
nameDB = c.fetchall()

c.execute("SELECT farmGrown FROM apples")
farmGrownDB = c.fetchall()

conn.commit()
conn.close()


# I assume that if I close the connection the cursor whould be positioned at the 
# first row again but this doesn't appear to be the case
conn = sqlite3.connect(dbName)

for i in range(len(appleIDDB)):
    c = conn.cursor()

    if ((nameDB[i][0] == appleCurrent[0]) and (farmGrownDB[i][0] == appleCurrent[1])):
        idCurrent = appleIDDB[i][0]
        print("This apple matches the apple stored with id number " +str(idCurrent))
        # This writes into the fifth row of the table
        c.execute('''INSERT INTO keyFeature(taste, texture, Colour)   
                   VALUES(?,?,?)''', (tasteCurrent, textureCurrent, colourCurrent))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

A [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) such as sqlite isn't quite like a table in a speadsheet. Instead of a list of rows with a certain order you just have "a big bag of rows" (technically called a set of tuples) and you can sort them any way you want.

The way we solve your problem, as you've already identified when you created the table, is to make sure every row has a **key** that allows us to identify it (like your apple ID). When we want this key to represent an ID in another table, that's called a [foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key). So we just need to add a foreign key (called `appleID`) to the `keyFeature` table, and use that whenever we add a row to it.

First, get rid of this from your first for loop, we don't need it at this stage, the table can sit empty.

```
c.execute('''INSERT INTO keyFeature(appleID)
                VALUES(?)''', (id[i],))
```

Next, you don't need to get the whole table to find the apple you want, you can just select the one you are interested in:

```
c.execute("SELECT appleID FROM apples WHERE name=? AND farm=?",("Pink Lady", "Farm 3"))
idCurrent = c.fetchone()[0]
```

The real trick is, when adding data to `keyFeature`, we have to insert all the data in one statement. This way a new tuple (row) is created with the ID and all the other information all at once. As if it were in "the right place" in the table.

```
c.execute('''INSERT INTO keyFeature(appleID, taste, texture, Colour)   
                   VALUES(?,?,?,?)''', (idCurrent, tasteCurrent, textureCurrent, colourCurrent))
```

Now we can retrieve information from the keyFeature table using the ID of the apple we're interested in.

```
c.execute("SELECT taste, texture, Colour FROM keyFeature WHERE apple_id=?", (my_apple_id,))
```

Final complete code:

```
import sqlite3

dbName = 'test.db'

################# Create the Database File ###################

# Connecting to the database file
conn = sqlite3.connect(dbName)
c = conn.cursor()

#Create the identification table with names and origin
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE apples(appleID INT PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, 
farmGrown TEXT)''')

#Create the table with key data
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE keyFeature(appleID INT PRIMARY KEY, taste INT, 
texture INT, Colour TEXT)''')

#Populate apples table and id in keyFeature table
AppleName = ['Granny Smith', 'Golden Delicious', 'Pink Lady', 'Russet']
appleFarmGrown = ['Farm 1', 'Farm 2', 'Farm 3', 'Farm 4']
id = []

for i in range(len(AppleName)):
    id.append(i+1)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO apples(appleID, Name, farmGrown)
                    VALUES(?,?,?)''', (id[i], AppleName[i], appleFarmGrown[i]))

#Current Apple to populate row in keyFeature
appleCurrent = ('Pink Lady','Farm 3')

tasteCurrent = 4
textureCurrent = 5
colourCurrent = 'red'

#Find ID and write into the database
c.execute("SELECT appleID FROM apples WHERE name=? AND farm=?",(appleCurrent[0], appleCurrent[1]))
idCurrent = c.fetchone()[0]

c.execute('''INSERT INTO keyFeature(appleID, taste, texture, Colour)   
                       VALUES(?,?,?,?)''', (idCurrent, tasteCurrent, textureCurrent, colourCurrent))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```